# Getting Exception "The type 'SerializableClass' is not mapped as a Table."

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, serialization

I just try to update one table using this code :

```
header.lng_LengthId = LengthId;
dc.OP_TetherLengths.Attach(currHeader, true);
dc.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, header);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Here **currheader** is the object containing existing value in table and **header** is the object of **Serializable class** with latest value.

Here is the defination of Serializable class :

```
[Serializable()]
public class TetherLengthHeader
{
    public int lng_LengthId { get; set; }
    public string str_systemid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dte_dateadded { get; set; }
    public string str_LengthId { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<double> dbl_newlength { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<bool> bln_deleted { get; set; }
    public string str_createdby { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> dte_created { get; set; }
    public string str_modifiedby { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> dte_modifieddate { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> lng_status { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> lng_lengthuom { get; set; } 
}
```

**Problem :**

when i try to update value i am getting this exception :

```
The type 'Common.Data.TetherLengthHeader' is not mapped as a Table.
```

please let me know where i am going in wrong direction.If you need more info then please let me know i will try to provide.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the issue where i was wrong.I was using **currHeader** in Attach method where i have to use **header** object.Now this issue solved using **header** in place of **currHeader** :

```
header.lng_LengthId = LengthId;
dc.OP_TetherLengths.Attach(header, true);
dc.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, header);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Thanks for All to spend some time on this issue.